# Error in geom_bar plot: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette

Tags: r

Why am I getting this error with the following code while working through Wickham & Grolemund, 2016 (R for Data Science):

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, color = clarity, fill = NA),
position = "identity")
```

The error reads: **Must request at least one colour from a hue palette**

The code gives the expected output when it is run as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = diamonds,
mapping = aes(x = cut, color = clarity)
) +
geom_bar(fill = NA, position = "identity")
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is expected behaviour here or not.

If you want the bars to be unfilled, you should put the argument `fill = NA` *outside* the `aes` call. For example, the following works fine:

```r
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, color = clarity), fill = NA, position = "identity")
```

[image]

Things are more complicated when you put the `NA` inside the `aes` call, because if you use a single value (like `NA`) as an aesthetic mapping, ggplot internally creates a whole column of `NA` values in its internal data frame and maps the aesthetic to that. That doesn't matter too much if you have a continuous color scale; in fact, your code works fine if you specify that you want a 'numeric-flavoured' `NA`:

```r
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, color = clarity, fill = NA_real_),position = "identity")
```

[image]

Note though that rather than the `fill = NA_real_` being interpreted as 'no fill', it is interpreted as 'fill with the default `NA` colour`, which is gray.

If you have a discrete type of `NA` such as `NA_character_` or just plain old `NA` (which is of class 'logical'), you get the error because when ggplot tries to set up the fill scale, it counts the number of unique non-`NA` values to fetch from its discrete color palette. It is the palette function that complains and throws an error when you ask it for 0 colours. In fact, the simplest code that replicates your error is:

```r
scales::hue_pal()(0)
#> Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.
```

The behaviour of ggplot has changed since 2016 when the tutorial you are following was written, so you would need to look back in the change log to see whether this was an intentional change, but the bottom line is that `fill = NA` should be used outside `aes` if you want the bars to be unfilled.